# Moving LWC to production with external Library ChartJS

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, charts, chartjs

I am trying to migrate my LWC that uses an external library Called LightningWebChartJS
Every time I am trying to migrate the component from Sandbox to Prod I get this error
No MODULE named markup://c:dataset found : [markup://c:dashboardCTL]

I wonder if the issue is because I am not migrating the LightningWebChartJS
The hierarchy look like the following:

```
force-app/main/default
--- LightningWebChartJS
--- LWC
------ dashboardCTL
```

and my xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed> true </isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

any idea how can I migrate the LightningWebChartJS I do not find it in my Outbound Message set
Do you think that this is causing the error ?

Comment: Do you have  any LWC named "dataset" in your sandbox ?

Comment: Nop ..  I wonder if it is not coming from the external library .. ChartJS .. but I do not understand how to migrate it to prod I can't find it in the Inbound Message Set